# How do I iterate over a list of functions and call those functions within the loop

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, function-call

So I'm trying to figure out how to make this block of code work, in particular, if I am to iterate over each function 'func' how can I then call that function.

```
def compare_two_hands(h1, h2):
    determinants = [is_flush(h), is_two_pair(h), is_one_pair(h)]
    for func in determinants:
        if func(h1) or func(h2):
            if func(h1) and func(h2):
                ...
            else:
                ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for *calling* the functions, as you have written it, will work.  The only problem is the way you have defined your list `determinants`.   I assume the three functions are defined elsewhere in the same namespace.  When you refer to them while building the list, simply lose the `(h)`:

```
def is_flush(h):
    ...

def is_two_pair(h):
    ...

def is_one_pair(h):
    ...

def compare_two_hands(h1, h2):
     determinants = [is_flush, is_two_pair, is_one_pair]
     # rest of function as you already have it
```